# How Can I get rid of the context dependency for using Theme on the Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

in short, I have a custom Theme file and I'm using that theme on the GetMaterialApp widget.
But when I use the that themes(for instance textStyle or Icon color), I always need to context.

I mean, there is my theme class at the below .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:professional_app/Utilities/colors.dart';

class CustomLightTheme {
  final ThemeData theme = ThemeData(
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      primary: Colors.blue,
      onPrimary: Colors.white,
    )),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
        bodyText2: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: "CormorantSC",
          fontSize: 16,
          color: colorOfPinkSwan.withOpacity(0.5),
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
        bodyText1: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24,
          color: Colors.white,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        )),
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
      buttonColor: colorOfDullLavender,
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: colorOfPerfume,
      foregroundColor: colorOfCinder,
    ),
  );
}
```

and I'm using that on the GetMaterialApp Widget:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("MyApp class has worked.");
    return GetMaterialApp(
      transitionDuration: durationOfLow,
      defaultTransition: Transition.fadeIn,
      getPages: getPages,
      theme: CustomLightTheme().theme,
      initialRoute: pathOfHomePage,
      unknownRoute:
          GetPage(name: pathOfErrorPage, page: () => const ErrorPage()),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

So, When I wanna use the that theme features, I always need to context. For example:

```
_text({required BuildContext context, required String text}) {
  return Text(
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
    text,
    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
    maxLines: 2,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  );
}
```

That is a method that return my text widget but I don't wanna send context like parameter to that text method.

is there any way to get rid of context dependency? Or Can I use GetX to that problem?

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:**

*create a variable on top of your **main.dart** file like below:*

```
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

**Step 2:**

add *navigatorKey* to your **GetMaterialApp** like below:

```
 return GetMaterialApp(
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  ...
);
```

**Now**

use this *navigatorKey* anywhere to access context using the following line:

```
navigatorKey.currentState!.overlay!.context
```

Comment: Nice solution to have application level `context` from anywhere in the app.

Comment: By the way, why can't we use just `navigatorKey.currentState!.context`?